# Increase kmemsize size of non-swappable kernel memory

Tags: centos, memory, memory-usage, kmemsize

I'm getting an error about not enough resources on a VPS running CentOS

The exact error has to do with non-swappable memory. Here are the stats

Current Use 29.35
Soft Limit 30
Hard Limit 33
Units MB

Server Total Memory 4.4GB

How do I increase this from 30 megs and what is a safe limit to set?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is an OpenVZ VPS. The command for setting the kmemsize is

vzctl set $VZID --kmemsize $barrier:$limit --save

which has to be executed on the hostsystem.

To tell a safe limit, one would need more data (e.g. if there are more VPSs on the same host, if yes: how many? etc.).

There's additional information about how to calculate safe values for UBC parameters in the OpenVZ-Wiki:

http://wiki.openvz.org/UBC_systemwide_configuration

Comment: When I run this command I get `Unable to open /dev/vzctl: No such file or directory
Please check that vzdev kernel module is loaded and you have sufficient permissions to access the file.
`

Comment: Are you sure you're using OpenVZ virtualization or is it something else?

Please also provide the output of `uname -a`

Comment: uname -a `Linux s15428881.example.info 2.6.18-028stab099.3 #1 SMP Wed Mar 7 15:20:22 MSK 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` and cat /proc/version is `Linux version 2.6.18-028stab099.3 (root@rhel5-build-x64) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)) #1 SMP Wed Mar 7 15:20:22 MSK 2012`

Comment: It seems you are trying to execute the command on the VPS. You have to execute it on the physical hostsystem.

If you don't have access to the hostsystem, there's no way to change container limits.